# Pipenv not activating in correct directory for virtual environment

Tags: python-3.x, macos, virtualenv, pipenv

Newbie to pipenv,

**TL;DR**: Trying to integrate pipenv with a project using venv from PyCharm and getting unexpected dictionary behaviour

**Background**: *Was* Using PyCharm to make virtual environments for a Python project. I was recommended to move onto pipenv so the project could be run on different machines easier.
Followed procedure to install pipenv to my knowledge correctly:

```
pip3 install pipenv
```

Pipenv also seems to be working correctly when using `sys.executable`

```
/Users/swapneel/.local/share/virtualenvs/Desktop-zQLGYB_4/bin/python
```

**Problem**: When I run `pipenv shell` in my project directory everything is written to my desktop i.e `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock`.
I also tried to use my requirements.txt with:

```
pipenv install -r requirements.text
```

Only to get the message:

```
Requirements file provided! Importing into Pipfile…
Requirements file doesn't appear to exist. Please ensure the file exists in your project directory or you provided the correct path.
```

Also, this is what displays when I try activate `pipenv` in my desired directory:

```
(Desktop) bash-3.2$
```

Here is my directory path. For clarity I included undesired Pipfiles in desktop:

```
Desktop
|-Pipfile
|-Pipefile.lock  
|--projects/
|  |--desired project/
|  |------------------__init__.py
|  |------------------main.py
|  |------------------requirements.txt
|  |------------------modules
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

**EDIT**:
Worth mentioning I was getting this error initially

```
Pipenv: Command Not Found' After 'pip install pipenv
```

which after some [research](https://gist.github.com/huruji/497f7a3859d1717cc462881e77754e09)

This seemed to fix

```
sudo -H pip install -U pipenv
```